# Passwordless login not working

Tags: apex, passwordless-login

I am trying to implement passwordless login using Apex for community user. But when calling method : `UserManagement.initPasswordlessLogin(String userId, Auth.VerificationMethod)` i am getting error:

> We couldn't perform a passwordless login because users are required to verify their identity to log in to the site

i am calling this method from guest user context and generating OTP, then verifying the OTP and logging in. it was working for some time and it suddenly stopped.

I checked the user i am trying to login already has `HasUserVerifiedEmailAddress = true`

for sample:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static String sendOTPforLogin(String uname) {
        try {
            List<User> users = [SELECT name, id, email FROM User WHERE username =:uname LIMIT 1];
            String identifier = UserManagement.initPasswordlessLogin(users[0].id, Auth.VerificationMethod.EMAIL);
            return identifier;
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new AuraHandledException (ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If `HasUserVerifiedEmailAddress = true` is indeed for the same user, this sounds like a bug or perhaps the error message is not indicative of the true root cause. Open a case with Support.